# Double slash; incorrect sudo path for pip

Tags: python, pip, jython, sudo

I've been trying to install `plotly`:

```
$ sudo pip install plotly
sudo: unable to execute /opt/jython/bin//pip: No such file or directory
```

The path is obviously corrupt, and I can't see why `sudo` got there in the first place:

```
$ whereis pip
pip: /usr/bin/pip /usr/bin/pip3.6 /opt/jython/bin/pip /opt/jython/bin/pip2.7
```

What is it?

Comment: When you `sudo`, it doesn't use your current environment, it uses a stripped-down environment defined in your `/etc/sudoers`, which usually does not include your `PATH`. There are additional details depending on your specific platform.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a Python question; it's a `sudo` question. It probably belongs on one of the other StackExchange sites, but which one depends on which platform you're on.

Comment: Meanwhile, you can always work around this with `sudo /usr/bin/pip`. Or you may want to create unique links like `pip2.7`, `pip3.6`, `jpip`, etc. that you can use.

Comment: Also, the double slash is almost certainly irrelevant here; why is it what you put in the question title?

Comment: Check your '/etc/profile.d/jython.sh' script

Answer (score 0):

Check

> '/etc/profile.d/jython.sh'

Comment: `$ cat /etc/profile.d/jython.sh 
export PATH="/opt/jython/bin/:$PATH"` . Looks nice enough, at least to my eye.

Comment: Set it to: export PATH="/opt/jython/bin:$PATH", removing the trailing backslash of the jthon path. Jython Pip is also adding another backslash while comcating the package.

Comment: Apparently, it is not enough: `$ cat /etc/profile.d/jython.sh 
export PATH="/opt/jython/bin:$PATH" $ sudo pip install plotly
sudo: unable to execute /opt/jython/bin//pip: No such file or directory`